# Git push --all vs --mirror

Tags: git, github, push

What is the difference between `git push --all` and `git push --mirror`?

I only know this:

- With deleted local branch, `--all` doesn't push it and `--mirror` does.

This is correct?

Any other differences?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As it says in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html):

> --all
>
>   Push all branches (i.e. refs under
>   `refs/heads/`
>   ); cannot be used
>      with other <refspec>.
>
> --mirror
>
>   ... specifies that all refs under
>   `refs/`
>   (which includes but is not limited to
>   `refs/heads/`
>   ,
>   `refs/remotes/`
>   , and
>   `refs/tags/`
>   ) be mirrored ...

So *a*, if not *the*, key difference is that one means `refs/heads/*` and one means `refs/*`.  The `refs/heads/*` names are the branch names.  Anything in `refs/remotes/` is a remote-tracking name, and anything in `refs/tags/` is a tag name.  Other notable name-spaces include `refs/notes/`, `refs/replace/`, and the singular `refs/stash`.

The `--mirror` option goes on to mention:

> locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end,
>    and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end.

Hence `--mirror` effectively implies both `--force` and `--prune`; `--all` does not.  You can, however, add `--force` and/or `--prune` to `git push --all`, if you like.

It is always up to the *other* Git to decide whether to obey polite requests (those sent without `--force`) or commands (`--force`) to make changes to its references.

> With deleted local branch, `--all` doesn't push it and `--mirror` does.

This is a consequence of the `--prune` option: telling your Git to use `--prune` means "ask them to delete names in their name-space(s) that are not in mine".

Comment: Ok, thanks you @torek . I posted this question because I had an error doing `push --all`. The problem was that I was not using `--force` option and documentation says `Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. This flag disables the check. This can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care.` This was my case because I have done a reset and delete some commits. This is correct?

Comment: Yes. Using `git reset` to move a branch name "backwards" requires some kind of force-push in general. If your Git is not too ancient, you have the "force with lease" option as well as straight `--force`, which lets you have your Git tell the other Git: *I believe your branch name B identifies some commit `<hash>` and if so, make B identify this other commit instead.* This one is safer, in that if you get it wrong, they reject the push with the error: *My B does not identify that commit, so I did nothing.*

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), you won't be able to use `git push --all` with `--mirror`.

And the problem is: `--all` is sometime *implied*, when you are *pushing* from a local repository you just cloned with `--mirror`.
[Filippo Valsorda](https://twitter.com/FiloSottile) made the unfortunate experience [recently](https://twitter.com/filosottile/status/1163918701462249472):

> Ok, git, WTF. This is not in the man pages.

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ECcR4vaXsAQ4bfm?format=jpg&name=4096x4096]

So, fix an earlier regression to "`git push --all`" which should have been forbidden when the target remote repository is set to be a mirror.

See [commit 8e4c8af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e4c8af058d7eb1b887184deb3bf79f3818b3a65) (02 Sep 2019) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fe048e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe048e4fd905e5c45b07381339ef627f57cf0822), 30 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### `push`: disallow `--all` and refspecs when `remote.<name>.mirror` is set

> Pushes with `--all`, or refspecs are disallowed when `--mirror` is given to 'git push', or when '`remote.<name>.mirror`' is set in the config of the repository, because they can have surprising effects.
> [800a4ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/800a4ab399e954b8970897076b327bf1cf18c0ac) ("`push`: check for errors earlier", 2018-05-16, Git  v2.18.0-rc0) refactored this code to do that check earlier, so we can explicitly check for the presence of flags, instead of their side-effects.
>
> However when '`remote.<name>.mirror`' is set in the config, the `TRANSPORT_PUSH_MIRROR` flag would only be set after we calling '`do_push()`', so the checks would miss it entirely.
>
> This leads to surprises for users (see above).
>
> Fix this by making sure we set the flag (if appropriate) before checking for compatibility of the various options.

That leads to, with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), a code cleanup.

See [commit 842385b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/842385b8a4fa56678f13cda599ee96463004e7bf), [commit 9dad073](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dad073d4b9b6679c3e86f28aacf79f85ed786d2), [commit 26e28fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26e28fe7bbdf8b22ed096dfd76a9311e86ffb200), [commit 75d3bee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75d3bee15778a3aaeb8234023fc224838ac53181), [commit 20f4b04](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20f4b044a681fffd469cc9ddcf055580a20fd612), [commit 5b9427e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b9427e0ac4d4b6c96f23fc5eb9b047a27563c65), [commit 8d2aa8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d2aa8dfac4048c964453a8983f1dc12ecdfe1c3), [commit 424e28f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/424e28fcadfe0a40e444687c10fb4eaff8360f8d), [commit e885a84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e885a84f1bc660adfc1dea5f6c25d0a92c7c9dbc), [commit 185e865](https://github.com/git/git/commit/185e86522678fed077d6cec02381bcf899bf24e5) (30 Sep 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 19dd352](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19dd352d03adc75d0b6530975a44b7bb23c69063), 05 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`push`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b9427e0ac4d4b6c96f23fc5eb9b047a27563c65): drop unused repo argument to `do_push()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> We stopped using the "repo" argument in [8e4c8af058](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e4c8af058d7eb1b887184deb3bf79f3818b3a65) ("`push`: disallow --all and refspecs when remote..mirror is set", 2019-09-02, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe048e4fd905e5c45b07381339ef627f57cf0822) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc12974a897308fd3254cf0cc90319078fe45eea)), which moved the `pushremote` handling to its caller.