# How do I push all branches to a new remote after commit history rewrite?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs-migrate

I have reviewed many existing pages on SO about this subject and none of the solutions works. I am running `git lfs migrate` on an existing repository with 80,000+ commits, and thousands of tickets and pullrequests. `git lfs migrate` rewrites commit history and we are applying it to all branches. I want to then force push all the changed branches to the original repo. This is the ultimate goal. Now for the tests I have been running that are the direct subject of this post.

In my tests, I clone the target repo and run the migration locally before attempting to set and push to a new repository at a different github url. After this is complete I go to GitHub and alas all the branches are gone except master. I've tried using `git push origin -u --all` and `--mirror` and other variants posted here on SO all to no avail. I even got creative and just ra `git push --mirror` but still only master appears on the GitHub repo page. The documentation at https://git-scm.com/ is clear but it does not have the expected affect.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `git push --mirror` means "push all refs", so `git for-each-ref` will show you what would get pushed. What refs do you have in the source repository?

Comment: When you did the clone of the target repo, did you do `git clone [--mirror](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---mirror)` to get a mirror of the source repository, including all the branches, on which you can then do the `git lfs migrate`? If you hadn't then your local clone won't have been a mirror, and pushing with `--mirror` won't have pushed the branches that you didn't have in your clone.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but since I've been struggling with the same for the past 2 months or so, here is my 50 cent on the matter.
When cloning the existing repo using `git clone` command so indeed only branch, default branch is being checkout. if you then execute `git lfs migrate --everything --include =....` then the git lfs migrate will only take place on this one single branch that was checkout. then if you try to `git push --mirror #newUrl#`, the --mirror flag is using the --prune option (as discussed here - [Git push --all vs --mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343025/git-push-all-vs-mirror)). This is why you will only see one branch after using the `git push --mirror` command.
Basically in order to overcome this annoying issue we:

1. git clone our current repository
2. using a shell script checkout every branch locally (so basic `git checkout #branchName#)
3. executed `git lfs migrate --everything --include`
4. once the migration done, we've executed `git push --mirror #newRepoUrl#`
   The `git push --mirror` here did two things:
   a. pushed all branches to the new repository
   b. pushed all refs as well, so branches, tags, replace, etc.
   This second option is really important as the `--everything` flag in the `git lfs migrate` command does taking care of all the refs, but regular `git push` or even `git push --all` (that covers only refs/branches as far as I know) and `git push --tags` (that covers refs/tags) won't push any other refs that might be changed during the `git lfs migrate` command. Using the `git push --mirror #newRepoUrl#` seems the only valid option.

Sorry for this longs post. If anyone has something to fix \ add \ change \ comment please feel free as it seems this topic is quite confusing.