# Project Export never completes and link expires

Tags: git, gitlab, export, git-filter-repo

My project is too big (9.9GB) because it has many commited versions of a ~400MB tar file. I was suggested to use filter-repo (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html). But I have to export the project.

I started the Export process and after I received a link by email (also there is a Download button on the export page). But when I try to download the exported file, I get this message:  "The file containing the export is not available yet; it may still be transferring. Please try again later."
How am I supposed to download the file? Please don't tell me that it cannot be exported because it is too big and there is no available space...

The download link is valid only for 24h. Maybe the export process is taking more than 24h...
Any hint to reduce the repo size?

Thank you

Luis

Answer (score 0):

> But I have to export the project.

You should not have to export a GitLab project to apply [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo).
You should only [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) the GitLab repository locally.

Once locally cloned:

- perform the `git filter-repo` ([for instance](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_content_based_filtering) `git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M`)
- Check the size of your local repository with [git-sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer)
- [`git push --mirror`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49343086/6309)

As usual, this kind of command rewrites history, so make sure to notify any collaborator.

The [OP LuisGomes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16987488/luisgomes) also mention [Reduce repository size with git-filter-repo](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/reduce-repository-size-with-git-filter-repo/39862).

That thread mentions the workaround:

> I had to create a new empty project and copy all the files from the big project to it.
> If you need, you can change the name and the path of the old project so the new project can have the original ones, and you won’t have to change other source codes.

Comment: Hello, Adam. I followed your instructions and used filter-repo to strip the blob related to the 400MB tgz file. But I need the last tgz, so I put it back. After doing `git push --mirror https://gitlab/myproject`, I saw that the project on Gitlab was taking the same 9.9GB space. WHat am I doing wrong? Thanks for your post.              PS. I am still trying to install git-sizer on CentOS 7.

Comment: @LuisGomes Not sure who "Adam" is, but can you check with your private Gitlab admins, or with GitLab support, what still takes so much space? Maybe it is the reflog, which still references old commits no longer part of your new branches.

Comment: Sorry, VonC. Adam was the guy who posted the first reply. I posted this question at the Gitlab forum first, but I got no answer so far. Thank you, VonC.

Comment: @LuisGomes OK, I will follow https://forum.gitlab.com/t/project-export-never-completes/58809.

Comment: I tried  to export the repository in order to shrink its size. If the export is not necessary, I can skip it. The thing is that I still can't see any size reducing even if the push command works. There is another user wit the same problem. I will follow him too.'https://forum.gitlab.com/t/reduce-repository-size-with-git-filter-repo/39862'

Comment: @LuisGomes Do you see a reduction in size in the local repository, where you have applied the `git filter-repo` command?

Comment: I think my post with the answer to your question and other comments was deleted, @VonC

Comment: @LuisGomes I have seen it indeed. But it should have been added to your question (by editing it) since answers are reserved for answers.

Comment: @LuisGomes I would recommend checking this case out with the GitLab support, to see if they can identify why the repository is still so large.